# There are too many arguments in my =IFERROR formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function, vlookup

I can't work out how I have too many arguments in this formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Table6,5,FALSE),0,(VLOOKUP(A2,Table6,5,FALSE)))
```

Can anyone help with how this is wrong?

Comment: IFERROR returns the first parameter if it doesn't create an error and the second parameter if the first does create an error so you only need two parameters.  `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Table6,5,FALSE),0)`

Comment: hey thanks so much for the speedy reply...Der on my part..That worked perfectly. Awesome

Comment: Why don't people answer in an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of an answer:

[Syntax](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/iferror-function-HA010342587.aspx) 
*IFERROR(value, value_if_error)*

The IFERROR function syntax has the following arguments:

•    *Value* Required. The argument that is checked for an error.
•    *Value_if_error* Required. The value to return if the formula evaluates to an error. The following error types are evaluated: #N/A, #VALUE!, #REF!, #DIV/0!, #NUM!, #NAME?, or #NULL!.

**Remarks**
•   If *value* or *value_if_error* is an empty cell, IFERROR treats it as an empty string value ("").
•   If *value* is an array formula, IFERROR returns an array of results for each cell in the range specified in *value*.

Thus, as suggested by @JerryJeremiah, leave out the third parameter so:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Table6,5,FALSE),0)
```

Early versions of Excel do not have IFERROR and for these a construct very similar to what did not work above (ie using three parameters) may be appropriate - and should still work in Excel 2010:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Table6,5,0)),0,VLOOKUP(A2,Table6,5,0))
```